# Geofence monitoring and notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-permissions, android-geofence

I'm new to Android Development and am doing my best to learn by working on little mini-projects.

Currently, I'm trying to build a very simple app that monitors a user's location and sends a notification when the user 'dwells' in the specified location (loitering delay = 5 mins), and when they exit the specified location.

I've tried to follow the Google documentation as best as possible, but I'm clearly missing something, because the app is not working as expected. So far the app runs and asks for location permission, but no notifications happen and so there is either something wrong with my geofence monitoring, my notifications, or both.

I'm hoping someone kind could perhaps point me in the right direction in terms of where I'm falling short.

My **MainActivity**:

```
package com.example.android.solidtimesheethelper;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import static android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED;
import static com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT;
import static com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BootReceiver bootReceiver = new BootReceiver();

    float RADIUS = 50;

    static final int REQUEST_CODE = 123;

    PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent;

    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;

    Geofence solidIsHere = new Geofence.Builder().setRequestId("solidBlockB")
            .setCircularRegion(-34.037612, 18.351883, RADIUS)
            .setExpirationDuration(NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL | GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .setLoiteringDelay(300000)
            .setNotificationResponsiveness(300000)
            .build();

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);
        builder.addGeofence(solidIsHere);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (geofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return geofencePendingIntent;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
        //        // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
        geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return geofencePendingIntent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED);
        this.registerReceiver(bootReceiver, filter);

        // Required if your app targets Android 10 or higher.
        registerGeofences(this);
//        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
//                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION + Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
//                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) ||
//                    ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
//                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
//                builder.setTitle("Grant Permissions");
//                builder.setMessage("This app cannot perform its function without access to your phone's location");
//                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
//                                MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
//                                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE
//                        );
//                    }
//                });
//                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
//                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
//                alertDialog.show();
//            } else {
//                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
//                        MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
//                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE
//                );
//            }
//        } else {
//            geofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
//                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geofences successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                            Log.v("MainActivity", "Geofences successfully added");
//                        }
//                    })
//                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
//                            Log.v("MainActivity", "Geofence add FAILED");
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geofence add FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        }
//                    });
//        }


    }

    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            registerGeofences(MainActivity.this);
        }
    }

    private void registerGeofences(Context context) {
        // Required if your app targets Android 10 or higher.
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION + Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) ||
                    ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Grant Permissions");
                builder.setMessage("This app cannot perform its function without access to your phone's location");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE
                        );
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE
                );
            }
        } else {
            geofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geofences successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.v("MainActivity", "Geofences successfully added");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.v("MainActivity", "Geofence add FAILED");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geofence add FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

My BroadcastReceiver for geofence transitions:

```
package com.example.android.solidtimesheethelper;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import static com.example.android.solidtimesheethelper.App.CHANNEL_ID;

public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

    static final String TAG = GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.

        switch (geofenceTransition) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
                Notification notificationDwell = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .setContentTitle("You've arrived!")
                        .setContentText("We're glad you're here safe.")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_EVENT)
                        .build();
                notificationManager.notify(1, notificationDwell);
                break;
//                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Bob")
//                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
//                        .setContentTitle("You're here!")
//                        .setContentText("We're glad you had a safe journey")
//                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                Notification notificationExit = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .setContentTitle("You've left!")
                        .setContentText("Enjoy your day!")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_EVENT)
                        .build();
                notificationManager.notify(1, notificationExit);
                break;
            default:
                Log.v(TAG, "No relevant transition");
        }
    }
}
```

Setting up notification channels:

```
package com.example.android.solidtimesheethelper;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;

public class App extends Application {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Channel1";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannels();
    }


    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Channel 1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you enable the feature in the api console? you also may need a key or some kind of authentication before you get events